# How to open two separate tabs in same google chrome window using webdriver and java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

I want to open two tabs in same window of google Chrome.I know this is common question. But none of the answers in them helped me to get this done. **I'm using Chrome driver and java** for it. I have tried to different code found on the internet and also in this website too. But none of them worked as I expected. It opened the window and load the website in first URL and then again load the second website in the same tab. It didn't  even open a another tab.

In short form this is what I want to do.....

1) Open a chrome and load a page (no problem with this step)
2) After 10 seconds **another tab** should open and load a website in the **same window**
3) Switch to the second tab and work in there

> I want to do this using Google Chrome and Java.

Comment: Are you going to interact then with that new tab?

Comment: Yes. second tab is the one I'm going to use while the first tab is kept open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the below code

```
driver.get(enter the url);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: first code works as I expected. But not the second code. In first code segment also you have to remove one line of these "driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");". If you could do I will accept this answer

Comment: @Joe thanks for your suggestion, i have updated the code

Comment: But still I can see the same code. Your first code segment works very well. Please remove the code segment. So that I can accept the answer immediatly

Comment: @Joe second code is removed